# Python Set Lookup Efficiency

Tags: python, list, set, big-o

I'm aware that python sets have O(1) lookup time and python lists have O(n) lookup time, but I'm curious about the container size at which it becomes worthwhile to convert a list to a set.

In other words, if I were to call the below:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(1000000):
    random.randint(1,3) in arr
```

would it be more efficient than the calling the following?

```
s = set([1, 2, 3])
for i in range(1000000):
    random.randint(1,3) in s
```

More importantly, what is the crossover length?

EDIT: The consensus is that this is entirely dependent on the efficient of the hash method of user defined objects, but for primitives like string, int, etc -- the cutoff is around 1-3.

Comment: You could try testing it, using `timeit` ;)

Comment: The crossover point is going to be different with different Python implementations, platforms, etc. So obviously, you need to test this for yourself.

Comment: It will also depend on what objects are in the list/set.  Objects can define how their hashes are calculated, so some objects may be faster to hash than others.

Comment: I feel like the choice of data structure should be obvious and dependant on your usage / algorithms.

Comment: @BrenBarn: But most expensive-to-hash type cache their hashes, so if you repeat the test 1M times with the same lookup value and the same collection, it shouldn't matter. (And if you've written your own expensive-to-hash type that doesn't doesn't cache its hashes, that's a pretty obvious optimization.)

Comment: @abarnert: That's also true, so it will also depend on how often you're hashing the same objects vs. new objects.  As all these comments show, there is no simple answer to the question :-)

Comment: @MadisonMay: In your fix randint will probably be slower than the lookup... (and the set construction as well)

Comment: One more thing worth noting: the time to do a lookups in either a list of a set of a handful of items is on the order of dozens to hundreds of nanoseconds. Is this really a hotspot in your program?

Comment: No, most definitely not.  I'm merely curious :)  Whenever I'm using the in operator I've been using sets regardless of how trivially small the list I'm calling the in operator on is, and I was curious to know whether or not this habit was actually beneficial, even if it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Where is the runtime of `set` documented? The [Set Types page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) mentions that they use hashes, so one could guess, but I wonder if is made official anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some code you can use to test it for yourself using [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
import timeit
for i in range(10):
    l = list(range(i))
    s = set(l)
    t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: None in l, )
    t2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: None in s)
    print(i, t1, t2)
```

You should run this on the platform and Python implementation that you actually care about.

Also notice that I'm searching for `None` rather than `1`, because searching for a value that's guaranteed to be the first (or second) thing in a list is constant-time, and that I'm using integers as in your initial test (which are, of course, trivial to hash). You should test on the actual data you care about.

Anyway, testing it on all of the implementations I have handy, I get a cutoff of 0 (64-bit PyPy 2.1.0/2.7.3) to 3 (32-bit PyPy 1.9.0/2.7.2), with most of them being 1-2. For example, here's 64-bit Python 3.3.2 crossing over at 1:

```
0 0.10865500289946795 0.11782343708910048
1 0.1330389219801873 0.11656044493429363
```

If you intentionally create an object that's slow to hash and doesn't cache, of course, you can push that cutoff as high as you want. For example, by putting a `time.sleep(1)` in my `__hash__` method, it ends up being around 12M.

Comment: This is a little unfair on `list`s - it must scan every element before it knows `None` is not there. If in the use case, the thing searched for is usually present, it would be more fair to either shuffle the list or look for the middle value of the range (ie: on average it needs to scan half the list). On my setup, the crossover is then at about 7000.

Comment: @drevicko: The fact that lists are linear is the whole point of what we're demonstrating, so it's hardly unfair to demonstrate that. Putting the value to find in the middle instead of the end (or not at all) only makes a 2x difference; maybe the cutoff before a set is better will be 2-3 instead of 1-2, but who cares?

Comment: oops! my bad! I must have been comparing µs to ns! I thought it was odd.